# How to Remove anything not letters or numbers from part of lines with Regular Expressions?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, text-editing

How do I remove anything not letters or numbers from part of lines in txt file?

More explaining I have `username:password` or `username;password`.

I want to edit the username only and remove anything that not letters or numbers from it without touch the password. I would like do it with Regular Expressions since I am using Emeditor For Large Files and I believe Regular Expressions work in both `Notepad++` and `Emeditor`.

What have I tried?
I did use `Find: [^a-z0-9:;]+` but cant skip the password after `:` or `;` so what I want to do is to skip line start from `:password here` and `;password here` and only remove none letters or numbers from username alone.

Sorry if I didn't describe everything well, admins can edit if possible.

**Full Example of lines:**

```
!start._1:stop.~1@
Sta%rs&:B!ge(s+R}\
#Step[14,:St,./\Ert`
~user@#%name^*)+:P@$$wor'";D
T&*est~!@#$%^&*()_+={}|\;pass;word123
user@#%name;password!#$~`'123
45Star^5#$Lord1:@T1esting!
u~s#e%r^n&a*m(e)t_e+s-t,:Pa:ssw/orD$+;
```

**Needed Result:**

```
start1:stop.~1@
Stars:B!ge(s+R}\
Step:St,./\Ert`
username:P@$$wor'";D
Test;pass;word123
username;password!#$~`'123
45Star5Lord1:@T1esting!
usernametest:Pa:ssw/orD$+;
```

Comment: We are not here to teach you how to use regular expressions. Can you please at least make an effort to find your own solution first? You have asked many many questions about regexp and you don't seem to learning from the answers given to you.

Comment: - [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
 - [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: i've learned a lot from the answers that given
and i ask this question because i tried a lot but i didn't figure out how to skip anything after the : and ; which will be the password
and thanks for your kindless anyway

Comment: So tell us what you tried and why it didn't work. From https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask: "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: alright i tried Find: [^a-z0-9:;] the problem this don't skip password
so if there anything not letters or numbers in the password will be removed too and i don't want this happen i want skip the line from : and ; included the password and only the work be in the username
but i don't know what to do in [^a-z0-9:;] to avoid the password

Comment: so ? if you can help would appreciate it

Comment: I'm no expert on advanced regex. I tried for about 1/2 hour and couldn't answer it.

Comment: I have a solution with visual studio code or sublime text, not notepad++ however. Don't know if you 'd be comfortable to install one and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done in one pass.
Here is a way to do the job with multiple passes:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^a-z0-9;:]*)([a-z0-9]*)(?1)(.*?[;:].+$)`
- Replace with: `$2$3`
- *Uncheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>    (Click here as many times as needed, it replaces only a part of invalid characters each time)

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : begining of line
  (                 : start group 1
    [^a-z0-9;:]*    : negative character class, 0 or more any character that is not alpha-num or colon or semicolon
  )                 : end group 1
  (                 : start group 2
    [a-z0-9]*       : character class, 0 or more alpha-num
  )                 : end group 2
  (?1)              : re-use the pattern in group 1 (ie. [^a-z0-9;:]*)
  (                 : group 3
    .*?             : 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    [;:]            : a colon or semicolon (the first that exists in a line)
    .+              : 1 or more any character but newline (the password)
    $               : end of line
  )                 : end group 3
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2      : content of group 2, the alpha-num part of the name
$3      : content of group 3, rest of the line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
start1:stop.~1@
Stars:B!ge(s+R}\
Step14:St,./\Ert`               <== I guess there is a typo in your request
username:P@$$wor'";D
Test;pass;word123
username;password!#$~`'123
45Star5Lord1:@T1esting!
usernametest:Pa:ssw/orD$+;
```

Comment: working prefect as always you amazing me @Toto Thanks so Much For Your Supportmanlike

Comment: @DeathRival: You're welcome, glad it helps.